# Magento Shopping Cart rule not working for US

Tags: magento, discount, magento-rules

I have an issue where a straight coupon code with a fixed price discount (74.99) is applied to any of a few sku.

I've never seen this happen before, but the code is applied just fine to any address in the EU, but outside the zone the code shows as applied and then doesn't display.

[image]
[image]

I considered the information in this discussion : [Magento: Shopping cart price rule gets applied, but discount not subtracted from subtotal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7908513/magento-shopping-cart-price-rule-gets-applied-but-discount-not-subtracted-from) but it doesn't really apply since in the same store I can apply it to test addresses in Spain and the UK.

Has anyone seen this behavior before?

Comment: A little more info...found out that no sales have ever happened to the US using a coupon code in which Free Shipping wasn't enabled.